# Having trouble reading data from columns

Tags: r, max, apply

I have data on ~280 individuals and a couple of dummy covariates called "foreign" and "prevgrad." The data look like this:

```
    Name    Program foreign prevgrad    
    ******* *******   0       0 
    ******* *******   0       0 
    ******* *******   1       1 
    ******* *******   0       0 
    ******* *******   1       1 
    ******* *******   0       1
```

Each person belongs to one program cluster, A or B. I've split the data into two subsets, A and B. I am trying to produce a simple maximum likelihood estimation and I tried to do the following:

```
    ##The density function for subset A
    PrA  <- function(u, piA0, piA1, piA2, piB0, piB1, piB2, z1, z2) {
   (1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-u^2/2))*3*exp(piA0+piA1*z1+piA2*z2+u  /(3*exp(piA0+piA1*z1+piA2*z2 + u)+5*exp(piB0+piB1*z1+piB2*z2))
    }

    logIntA  <- function(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2, zee1, zee2) {
    log(integrate(function(u, piA0=a0, piA1=a1, piA2=a2, piB0=b0, piB1=b1, piB2=b2, z1=zee1, z2=zee2) PrA(u, piA0 = piA0, piA1 =piA1, piA2=piA2, piB0 = piB0, piB1 =piB1, piB2=piB2, z1=z1, z2=z2), lower=-10, upper=10)$integral)
    }

    #The density function for subset B
    PrB  <- function(u, piA0, piA1, piA2, piB0, piB1, piB2, z1, z2) {
    (1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-u^2/2))*5*exp(piB0+piB1*z1+piB2*z2)/(3*exp(piA0 + piA1*z1 +piA2*z2 + u)+5*exp(piB0+piB1*z1+piB2*z2))
    }

     logIntB  <- function(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2, zee1, zee2) {
     log(integrate(function(u, piA0=a0, piA1=a1, piA2=a2, piB0=b0, piB1=b1, piB2=b2, z1=zee1, z2=zee2) PrB(u, piA0 = piA0, piA1 =piA1, piA2=piA2, piB0 = piB0, piB1 =piB1, piB2=piB2, z1=z1, z2=z2), lower=-10, upper=10)$integral)
    }

    ##The maximum likelihood statistic
    toMax2  <- function(t) {
    piA0=t[1]
    piA1=t[2]
    piA2=t[3]
    piB0=t[4]
    piB1=t[5]
    piB2=t[6]
    (sum(apply(studentsA[,c('foreign','prevgrad')],1, function(s) logIntA(piA0, piA1, piA2, piB0, piB1, piB2, s['foreign'], s['prevgrad'])))+sum(apply(students.AB[,c('foreign','prevgrad')],1, function(s) logIntB(piA0, piA1, piA2, piB0, piB1, piB2, s['foreign'], s['prevgrad']))))
   }
```

I couldn't find relevant examples in the documentation on 'apply.' Currently I am getting the error "non-numeric argument to mathematical function." I can't figure out how to make z1 equal 'foreign' and z2 equal  prevgrad' in each row (i.e. for each individual).

Seems like a simple fix but as you can probably tell I am a newbie. I'd appreciate any suggestions (including general improvements to the code). Thanks!

Comment: I don't think indexing the row vector `s` is your problem. If you are using the `integrate(...)` function in base R, there is no `$integral` element in the returned list. What you want is `$value`. I suspect this is causing you to take the `log(NULL)`, which would cause that error.

Comment: BTW: There are several packages in R that make what you are trying to do much easier. See the [`likelihood`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/likelihood/likelihood.pdf) package, and `mle(...)` in the stats4 package, and `logLik(...)` in base R.